# Javascript - Create instance with array of arguments

Tags: javascript

I know the possibility to call a function with an array of arguments with apply(obj,args);
Is there a way to use this feature when creating a new instance of a function?

I mean something like this:

```
function A(arg1,arg2){
    var a = arg1;
    var b = arg2;
}

var a = new A.apply([1,2]); //create new instance using an array of arguments
```

I hope you understand what i mean... ^^^

Thanks for your help!

**Solved!**

I got the right answer. To make the answer fit to my question:

```
function A(arg1,arg2) {
    var a = arg1;
    var b = arg2;
}

var a = new (A.bind.apply(A,[A,1,2]))();
```

Comment: Important note: it doesn't matter what the first element of that array is. For example, `new (A.bind.apply(A,['cats',1,2]))();` will work just as well. The reason for this is that `new` ignores the `this` value provided to bind.

Comment: With the shorthand version provided, you don't need the last two brackets '()'.
Thus it could be: `var a = new (A.bind.apply(A, [null].concat([1, 2])));`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
var wrapper = function(f, args) {
    return function() {
        f.apply(this, args);
    };
};

function Constructor() {
    this.foo = 4;
}
var o = new (wrapper(Constructor, [1,2]));
alert(o.foo);
```

We take a function and arguments and create a function that applies the arguments to that function with the this scope.

Then if you call it with the new keyword it passes in a new fresh `this` and returns it.

The important thing is the brackets

`new (wrapper(Constructor, [1,2]))`

Calls the new keyword on the function returned from the wrapper, where as

`new wrapper(Constructor, [1,2])`

Calls the new keyword on the wrapper function.

The reason it needs to be wrapped is so that `this` that you apply it to is set with the new keyword. A new `this` object needs to be created and passed into a function which means that you must call `.apply(this, array)` inside a function.

Live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/pSpz8/)

Alternatively you could use ES5 [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method

```
var wrapper = function(f, args) {
    var params = [f].concat(args);
    return f.bind.apply(f, params);
};
```

See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/pSpz8/4/)

Comment: Very nice. +1 Building off of yours, it may be desirable to have `wrapper` return the function to a variable with the identifier you want so you can call `new` from that, giving `instanceof` the result you'd expect. http://jsfiddle.net/pSpz8/2/

Comment: ...or not (to my jsFiddle). After some sleep, I see that I missed the point of the question.

Comment: Thanks, this is really good. But the problem of this is, that the Object that is generated, is not of type Constructor. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: @FlashFan that's difficult to do without native `.bind` support. Alternatively you can start building it into the prototype chain but that just makes a mess of your prototype chain. See edited question though.

Comment: Hey this is a really great trick! Thanks very much for that! It took me minutes to understand it :P I've added this as a "one-liner" to my question ;)

Comment: @Raynos - Copying over the prototype works for me (see below). Can you think of any other gotchas?

Comment: Important note: it doesn't matter what array you concat with, as long as it contains exactly one element. For example, `var params = ['cats'].concat(args);` will work just as well. The reason for this is that `new` ignores the `this` value provided to bind.

Answer (score 7):

with ECMAscript 5 you can:

```
function createInstanceWithArguments (fConstructor, aArgs) {
    var foo = Object.create(fConstructor.prototype);
    fConstructor.apply(foo, aArgs);
    return foo;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

@Raynos answer works well, except that the non-ES5 version is missing the constructor's prototype after instantiation.

Here's my updated `cApply` method:

```
var cApply = function(c) {
  var ctor = function(args) {
    c.apply(this, args);
  };
  ctor.prototype = c.prototype;
  return ctor;
};
```

Which can be used like this:

```
var WrappedConstructor = cApply(Constructor);
var obj = new WrappedConstructor([1,2,3]);

// or inline like this.    
var obj2 = new (cApply(Constructor))([1,2,3]);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WLCT2/) for reference.

Comment: Best solution - I tweaked your solution to not have to pass an array, but use the wrapped constructor like normal, eg. `new WrappedConstructor(1,2,3)`. I also added the constructor to the prototype for good measure - **forked jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pBJn4/**

Comment: Unfortunately there doesn't seem a way to keep the original constructor for the return type, which would be bad for `obj instanceof Constructor` cases

Comment: Definitely agree, hacks like this are less than optimal. ES5 FTW.

Answer (score 3):

You can curry the functions:

```
function A(arg1, arg2) {
    // ...
}

function A12() {
    A(1, 2);
}
```

You could even build a curry factory:

```
function A_curry() {
    var args = arguments;
    return function () {
        A.apply(null, args);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Object.create()` to build the new instance, and call the constructor on the instance after that:

```
var args = [1,2,3];
var instance = Object.create(MyClass.prototype);
MyClass.apply(instance, args);
```

or in a single line:

```
var instance = MyClass.apply(Object.create(MyClass.prototype), args);
```

but don't forget `return this;` in `MyClass` by this single line solution.

If you don't have `Object.create()`, then it is very simple to write one:

```
Object.create = function (source){
    var Surrogate = function (){};
    Surrogate.prototype = source;
    return new Surrogate();
};
```

You can optionally write an `Function.newInstance()` or a `Function.prototype.newInstance()` function:

```
Function.newInstance = function (fn, args){
    var instance = Object.create(fn.prototype);
    fn.apply(instance, args);
    return instance;
};
```

so `var instance = Function.newInstance(MyClass, args);`.

*note: It is not recommended to override native classes.*

Answer (score 0):

What if you have your object class name stored in a variable called `className` ?

```
var className = 'A'
```

According to [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8843181/1697459) it all becomes very clean and simple using **ECMAScipt5**'s `Function.prototype.bind` method.

With an array of arguments:

```
new ( Function.prototype.bind.apply( className, arguments ) );
```

Or with an argument list:

```
new ( Function.prototype.bind.call( className, argument1, argument2, ... ) );
```

A single line, no need for a wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue and also wanted to preserve prototype properties of the target object. After looking at the answers, just came up with a rather simple solution. Thought I might as well share it for any future seeker :)

```
// Define a pseudo object that takes your arguments as an array
var PseudoObject = function (args) {
    TargetObject.apply(this, args);
};
// if you want to inherit prototype as well
PseudoObject.prototype = new TargetObject();

// Now just use the PseudoObject to instantiate a object of the the OtherObject
var newObj = new PseudoObject([1, 2, 3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It can now be done using the spread operator:

```
let a = new A(...[1,2]);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#examples