# Add self executing init method to constructor function?

Tags: javascript

Let’s say I have a constructor function which I do not have access to. Into this constructor function I want to **inject a self executing init method which gets executed whenever a new instance gets created from this constructor**.

For example: let’s say there is a Cat constructor, but I unfortunatly do not have access to it:

```js
function Cat() {
    // ...code which I do not have access to
    // ...maybe it comes from an external file or something?
}
```

And I can now of course do this to create new cats:

```js
var coolCat = new Cat();
```

All is well and I have my new cat instance.

But now what I want is (**if I actaully had access to the Cat constructor function body, which of course I do not!**) something like this:

```js
function Cat() {
  this.roarOnInit = function() {
    alert(’ROOOAAAR!’);
  };
  this.roarOnInit();
}
```

…so that when I do this:

```js
var coolCat = new Cat();
```

…I actually get that cool ROAR-alert box!

I do understand how to add the method roarOnInit to the Cat constructor (Cat.prototype.roarOnInit = function …) but is there a way that I easily can add the call to the method (which gets executed whenever a Cat instance is created) to the constructor body?

**This seems like such a trivial thing, and it’s probably super easy, but I just can’t seem to figure this out this afternoon!** Thanks for bearing with me.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the answers so far! I did forget one very important thing, and that is that I will not know in advance what the constructor function will be, or it's name etc. This is because I'm running this through a function which accepts any constructor as a parameter, and eventually returns the constructor (with it's original name/prototype) back.

Comment: I wonder who DVed and VTCed this. It's a fine question. +1

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with this definition of `Cat`:

```
function Cat(name){
this.name=name;
}
Cat.prototype.meow=function(){alert(this.name)}
```

Now, what we can do is to overwrite this with a new constructor that returns a regular `Cat`, but only after running our script:

```
var oldCat = Cat;
function Cat(name){
    var self=new oldCat(name);
    self.roarOnInit=function(){alert("ROOOOAAARRR")};
    self.roarOnInit();
    return self;
}
```

We can now do `new Cat("Muffin")`, and it will roar, and we'll still have access to properties on the original `Cat` prototype chain. I show this in an example snippet:

```js
// just to be safe, define the original as oldCat()

function oldCat(name){
  this.name=name;
}
oldCat.prototype.meow=function(){alert(this.name)}


//var oldCat = Cat;
function Cat(name){
  var self=new oldCat(name);
  self.roarOnInit=function(){alert("ROOOOAAARRR")};
  self.roarOnInit();
  return self;
}

var coolCat = new Cat("Muffin");
coolCat.meow();
```

Now, if you want to abstract this to accept any function, it's not too hard. We just have to do a bit of work with the constructor, to pass arguments. [Javascript - Create instance with array of arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054926/javascript-create-instance-with-array-of-arguments)

```
function injectToConstructor(C){
    return function(){
        var self = new (C.bind.apply(C,[C].concat([].slice.call(arguments))))();
        console.log("object initiated:");
        console.log(self);
        return self;
    };
}
```

Then we can do something like:

```
Cat = injectToConstructor(Cat);
var coolCat = new Cat("Muffin"); // logs 2 items
coolCat.meow();
```

Comment: Thank you, I did however forget to mention one vital piece of information and I have now added it to the question!

Comment: This alters the original name of the original constructor, and it has to be the same before as well as after the injected init method. I can not alter the name of  the constructor when doing instantiation of new instances. Cat needs to work before as well as after the "injection" code.

Comment: I just added an update that should take any item and doesn't alter the name.

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appreciate it!

The problem though is that I do not know the name of the passed constructor, meaning I can not do the ```Cat = injectToConstructor(Cat)``` since I do not know what the constructor name is.

This is hard to explain in a comment, but I've got this function which takes a constructor as a param, called "passedConstructor". If I console.log this I get (with the cat Example) "function Cat() { // etc. }", but if i run the passedConstructor through your function, I get the inner function (of your function) instead when I log it, meaning it breaks.

HARD to explain!

Comment: Why do you need to preserve the function?

Comment: @KristofferK: If you want to use AOP and injections, your code must not rely on the code of the function, and not on its identity either. And what could `console.log` possibly break?

Comment: One reason is that I need the .name property of the passedConstructor.

Comment: @Bergi it does not break anything, it just illustrates that for example the .name property gets changed, and that property must not get changed.

Comment: @KristofferK: No code should rely on `.name` properties (it won't work in IE at all for example). If you really need it, you'll have to resort to [arcane magic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24032179/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi I'm using an IE polyfill which does just fine for the browsers I need to support.

Comment: @Bergi also: this could (but is not in this case) be on the server. :)

Answer (score 1):

> This is because I'm running this through a function which accepts any constructor as a parameter, and eventually returns the constructor (with it's original name/prototype) back.

You cannot really. It's impossible to alter a function's behaviour, no way to "inject" code into it. The only way is to wrap the function, i.e. [decorate it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21243884/1048572), and return a new one.

In your example, it would look like so:

```
function makeRoarer(constr) {
    function Roar() { // new .name and .length, but that shouldn't matter
        constr.apply(this, arguments);
        this.roarOnInit();
    }
    Roar.prototype = constr.prototype;
    Roar.prototype.constructor = Roar;
    Roar.prototype.roarOnInit = function() {
        alert(’ROOOAAAR!’);
    };
    return Roar;
}
```

```
class Cat { … } // whatever
var a = new Cat(); // nothing
Cat = makeRoarer(Cat);
var b = new Cat(); // ROOOAAAR!
```